Ionic 6. Критует приложение после обновления compileSdkVersion. @Capacitor/share
Наш проект написан на Angular 14, Ionic 6, Capacitor 5.
Всё работало корректно, но после обновления compileSdkVersion и targetSdkVersion с 33й до 34й версии - приложение стало выбрасывать ошибку.
Нашли причину в плагине, оказалось, что @capacitor/share не работает с такой версией SDK.
Ошибка с Logcat

FATAL EXCEPTION: main


Process: com.hps.developer, PID: 1992
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.hps.developer/com.hps.developer.MainActivity}:
java.lang.SecurityException: com.hps.developer: One of
RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a
receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4164)
at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4322)
at
android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
at
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
at
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2685)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: com.hps.developer: One of
RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a
receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3069)
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3053)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3036)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2978)
at
android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.registerReceiverWithFeature(IActivityManager.java:6157)
at
android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1913)
at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1853)
at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1841)
at
android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:772)
at
android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:772)
at
com.capacitorjs.plugins.share.SharePlugin.load(SharePlugin.java:44)
at com.getcapacitor.PluginHandle.loadInstance(PluginHandle.java:115)
at com.getcapacitor.PluginHandle.load(PluginHandle.java:105)
at com.getcapacitor.PluginHandle.(PluginHandle.java:65)
at com.getcapacitor.Bridge.registerPlugin(Bridge.java:669)
at com.getcapacitor.Bridge.registerAllPlugins(Bridge.java:625)
at com.getcapacitor.Bridge.(Bridge.java:223)
at com.getcapacitor.Bridge.(Unknown Source:0)
at com.getcapacitor.Bridge$Builder.create(Bridge.java:1544)
at com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity.load(BridgeActivity.java:42)
at com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity.onCreate(BridgeActivity.java:36)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8975)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8944)
at
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4146)
at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4322) 
at
android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
at
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) 
at
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2685) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578)                                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)

По ошибке вижу, что что-то с методом плагина load, а именно со строкой
getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.EXTRA_CHOSEN_COMPONENT));

Как пофиксить ошибку или какие есть альтернативы этого плагина?
